# Invariant of $2 \times 2$ Matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, nonlinear-system

Given $\frac{b_{n}}{b}= trace S^{k} A= \displaystyle \sum_{j=0}^k=\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{min ({k-j, j)}} {k-j \choose i}{j \choose j-i}a^{k-j-i}b^{i}c^id^{j-i}$ where $n=k+1, s=i \ $  and $ \ m=j+i $. Let $A^n=A^{n-1}A= \
   M=
  \left( {\begin{array}{cc}
   a_{n-1} & b_{n-1}  \\
   c_{n-1} & d_{n-1} \\
  \end{array} } \right)\left( {\begin{array}{cc}
   a & b  \\
   c & d \\
  \end{array} } \right)$.

And I get the recursive equations:
$$\begin{cases}a_n=aa_{n-1}+cb_{n-1}\\b_n=ba_{n-1}+db_{n-1}\\c_n=ac_{n-1}+cd_{n-1}\\d_n=bc_{n-1}+dd_{n-1}\end{cases}$$

Show that $$b_n = \displaystyle \sum_{s=0}^{[\frac{n-1}{2}]} \displaystyle \sum_{m=0}^{{n-2s-1}} {n-s-m-1 \choose s}{m+s \choose m}a^{n-2s-m-1}b^{s+1}c^s d^{m}$$.
However, I don't know what is $b_{n-1}$ and $a_{n-1}.$ I just knew that it uses recurrence equation. How, will I prove this?

Comment: "$= trace S^{k} A= \displaystyle \sum_{j=0}^k=$" - is there something missing?